Mark a view function as being exempt from the CSRF view protection
(function) def csrf_exempt(view_func: _F@csrf_exempt) -> _F@csrf_exempt
Mark a view function as being exempt from the CSRF view protection.
Make sure disabling CSRF protection is safe here. sonarlint(python:S4502)
How to fix this issue on sonarcloud?.
(function) def csrf_exempt(view_func: _F@csrf_exempt) -> _F@csrf_exempt
Mark a view function as being exempt from the CSRF view protection.
Make sure disabling CSRF protection is safe here. sonarlint(python:S4502)

Do what the error message says (i.e. make sure disabling CSRF protection is safe)?

How to solve? Do what it says. Don’t exempt from CSRF protection.

If you understand what you do, and want to leave csrf_exempt in your code, you can suppress this issue only for this line with NOSONAR directive:
def csrf_exempt(view_func: _F@csrf_exempt) -> _F@csrf_exempt:  #NOSONAR

